# Xsl template for tree structure

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml structure. In xslt template for each position () in each list() I need to find position which attribute @out = 1,
then I need to create a tree structure of categories it belongs to using positon's @pid attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <Good id = "2196">
    <lists>
        <list  num="1050" id = "2531" description="Список оборудования и материалов двойного назначения и соответствующих технологий, применяемых в ядерных целях">
          <part  num="1">
            <pos  isKey="0" id="2532" pid="2531" description="Раздел 1. Промышленное оборудование" />
            <pos  num="1.2." isKey="0" id="2554" pid="2532" description="Испытательное и производственное оборудование" />
            <pos  num="1.2.6." isKey="0" id="2591" pid="2554" description="Системы для вибрационных испытаний, оборудование и компоненты, такие, как:" />
            <pos  num="1.2.6.1." isKey="1" id="2592" pid="2591" description="Электродинамические системы для вибрационных испытаний" />
            <pos  num="1.2.6.4." isKey="1" id="2595" pid="2591" description="Конструкции для крепления испытуемой детали и электронные блоки" />
          </part>
        </list>
        <list  num="1090" id = "3029" description="Список оборудования, материалов и технологий, которые могут быть использованы при создании ракетного оружия">
          <part  num="2">
            <pos  isKey="0" id="3033" pid="3029" description="КАТЕГОРИЯ II" />
            <pos  isKey="0" id="3040" pid="3033" description="Раздел 9. Измерительное, навигационное и пеленгаторное оборудование и системы" />
            <pos  isKey="0" id="3041" pid="3033" description="Раздел 10. Системы управления полетом" />
            <pos  isKey="0" id="3043" pid="3033" description="Раздел 12. Оборудование для обеспечения пуска" />
            <pos  isKey="0" id="3046" pid="3033" description="Раздел 15. Испытательные системы и оборудование" />
            <pos  num="9.2." isKey="0" id="3333" pid="3040" description="Испытательное и производственное оборудование" />
            <pos  num="9.2.1." isKey="0" id="3334" pid="3333" description="Производственное, испытательное.." />
            <pos  num="9.2.1.2" isKey="0" id="3339" pid="3334" description="Испытательное оборудование для инерциальной аппаратуры:" />
            <pos  num="9.2.1.2.3." isKey="1" id="3342" pid="3339" description="Испытательный стенд стабилизирующего элемента ИИБ;" />
            <pos  num="9.2.1.2.5." isKey="1" id="3344" pid="3339" description="Установка для проверки и настройки гироскопа;" />
            <pos  num="9.2.1.2.9." isKey="1" id="3348" pid="3339" description="Центрифуга для проверки подшипников (опор) гироскопа;" />
            <pos  num="9.2.1.2.10." isKey="1" out="1" id="3349" pid="3339" description="Установка для осевой регулировки акселерометра;" />
            <pos  num="9.2.1.2.11." isKey="1" id="3350" pid="3339" description="Установка для проверки акселерометра" />
            <pos  num="9.2.2." isKey="0" id="3351" pid="3333" description="Испытательное, калибровочное и регулировочное оборудование:" />
            <pos  num="9.2.2.3." isKey="1" id="3354" pid="3351" description="Динамические моделирующие стенды/столы вращения)" />
            <pos  num="9.2.2.4." isKey="1" id="3355" pid="3351" description="Поворотные столы" />
            <pos  num="9.2.2.5." isKey="1" id="3356" pid="3351" description="Центрифуги, способные создавать ускорения более 100 g" />
            <pos  num="10.2." isKey="0" id="3373" pid="3041" description="Испытательное и производственное оборудование" />
            <pos  num="10.2.1." isKey="1" id="3374" pid="3373" description="Испытательное, калибровочное и регулировочное оборудование" />
            <pos  num="12.1." isKey="0" id="3399" pid="3043" description="Оборудование, сборочные единицы и комплектующие" />
            <pos  num="12.1.1." isKey="1" id="3400" pid="3399" description="Устройства и приборы, разработанные или модифицированные для обслуживания, проверки" />
        </part>
        </list>
        <list  num="1030" id="6648" description="Список товаров и технологий двойного назначения, которые могут быть использованы при создании вооружений и военной техники">
          <part  num="4">
            <pos  isKey="0" id="6679" pid="6648" description="Раздел 4. Товары и технологии, вывоз которых с территории РФ" />
            <pos  isKey="0" id="6681" pid="6679" description="Категория 2. Перспективные материалы" />
            <pos  num="2.2." isKey="0" id="11599" pid="6681" description="Испытательное, контрольное и производственное оборудование" />
            <pos  num="2.2.1." isKey="1" id="11600" pid="11599" description="Оборудование для тепловых испытаний образцов материалов с углерод-углеродным покрытием" />
```

For example for position with num "9.2.1.2.10." I need some output like that in word document:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Список оборудования, материалов и технологий, которые могут быть использованы |
 | при создании ракетного оружия                                                 |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | КАТЕГОРИЯ II                                                                  |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Раздел 9. Измерительное, навигационное и пеленгаторное оборудование и системы |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 9.2.       | Испытательное и производственное оборудование                    |
 | 9.2.1.     | Производственное, испытательное..                                |
 | 9.2.1.2.   | Испытательное оборудование для инерциальной аппаратуры           |
 | 9.2.1.2.10.| Установка для осевой регулировки акселерометра                   |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But if I want 4 positions with nums "9.2.1.2.10", "10.2.1","2.2.1","2.2.2", I need some output like that:

```
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Список оборудования, материалов и технологий, которые могут быть использованы |
 | при создании ракетного оружия                                                 |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | КАТЕГОРИЯ II                                                                  |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Раздел 9. Измерительное, навигационное и пеленгаторное оборудование и системы |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 9.2.       | Испытательное и производственное оборудование                    |
 | 9.2.1.     | Производственное, испытательное..                                |
 | 9.2.1.2.   | Испытательное оборудование для инерциальной аппаратуры           |
 | 9.2.1.2.10.| Установка для осевой регулировки акселерометра                   |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Раздел 10. Системы управления полетом                                         |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 10.2.      | Испытательное и производственное оборудование                    |
 | 10.2.1     | Испытательное, калибровочное и регулировочное оборудование       |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Список товаров и технологий двойного назначения, которые могут быть           |
 |использованы при создании вооружений и военной техники                         |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Раздел 4. Товары и технологии, вывоз которых с территории РФ                  |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Категория 2. Перспективные материалы                                          |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | 2.2.       | Испытательное, контрольное и производственное оборудование       |
 | 2.2.1.     | Оборудование для тепловых испытаний образцов материалов...       |
 | 2.2.2.     | Оборудование для тепловых испытаний образцов материалов...       |
 +-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So far I tried something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


<xsl:template match="/">

  <html>
  <body>
  <h2>Lists</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>parentID</th>
      </tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/goods/good/list/part/pos[@out=1]"/>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/goods/good/list/part/pos[@out=1]">
<xsl:variable name="pid" select="./@pid" />
  Key node: <span style="color:#ff0000">
  <xsl:value-of select="./@num"/><xsl:text>, id =  </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="./@id"/><xsl:text>, pid =  </xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="./@pid"/>
</span><br/>
<xsl:call-template name = "while">
 <xsl:with-param name="param" select="$pid"/>
</xsl:call-template>


  <br />
</xsl:template>



<xsl:template name = "while">
<xsl:param name="param"/>
<xsl:variable name="pid" select="../pos[@id = $param]/@pid"/>

<tr>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../pos[@id = $param]/@id"/></td>
<td><xsl:value-of select="../pos[@id = $param]/@pid"/></td>
</tr>

Param: <span style="color:#ff0000">
<xsl:value-of select="$param"/>
</span>

Inner var: <span style="color:#ff0000">
<xsl:value-of select="$pid"/>
</span>


<xsl:if test="$pid">
<br/>
<xsl:call-template name = "while">
 <xsl:with-param name="param" select="$pid"/>
</xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

May be there is a better way to fulfill this task?

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I use xsl 1.0, above I added what I have tried so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the chain of `pid` to `id` links it appears to be the rule that you need two separate columns for `pos` elements that have a `num` attribute and one two-column-spanning `td` for the other cases (`pos` elements with no `num`, or elements that are not called `pos`).  You can follow the chains using a *key*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <!-- key to look up any element with an id attribute based on the value of
       that id -->
  <xsl:key name="elementById" match="*[@id]" use="@id" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <h2>Lists</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@out = '1']" mode="table" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="table">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- the main recursive logic - first produce the output for the next
       item in the pid->id chain, then produce a row for this element -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elementById', @pid)" />
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="@description" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special case for pos elements with a @num - produce two columns -->
  <xsl:template match="pos[@num]">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elementById', @pid)" />
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@num" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@description" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The recursion will automatically stop when we reach an element with no `pid` attribute, as the key will match nothing in this case.

---

If you want to de-duplicate and group the parent links in the tree then you'll have to work top-down rather than bottom-up, following the links in reverse:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />

  <!-- key to look up any element with an id attribute based on the value of
       that id -->
  <xsl:key name="elementsByPid" match="*[@pid]" use="@pid" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <h2>Lists</h2>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Good/lists/list" mode="table" />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="table">
    <xsl:variable name="shouldOutput">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="shouldOutput" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($shouldOutput)">
      <table>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
      </table>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- the main recursive logic - first produce output for this row, then
       process any of the children (in the id->pid chain) that need to be
       output -->
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="row" />
    <xsl:for-each select="key('elementsByPid', @id)">
      <xsl:variable name="shouldOutput">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="shouldOutput" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="string-length($shouldOutput)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="row">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><xsl:value-of select="@description" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special case for pos elements with a @num - produce two columns -->
  <xsl:template match="pos[@num]" mode="row">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@num" /></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@description" /></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>


  <!-- check whether this node should be output by checking whether it, or any
       of its descendants in the id->pid tree, has @out=1.  The template will
       return an empty RTF for nodes that should not be output, and an RTF
       containing a text node with one or more "1" characters for nodes that
       should.  -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@out='1']" mode="shouldOutput">1</xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="shouldOutput">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elementsByPid', @id)"
         mode="shouldOutput"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will be rather inefficient for a large input document, because it has to follow the whole chain of id->pid links down to the bottom at every level to check whether the current node has *any* `out="1"` descendants in the chain.  If you could pre-process the document to work out these chains in advance and label every link in the chain with `out="1"` then the logic would be much simpler and more efficient.

Comment: Ok, but not exactly what I wanted, with your code I have such output if I want positions 2.2.1 and 2.2.2 to be detailed:

Список товаров и технологий ...
Раздел 4. Товары и технологии..
Категория 2. Перспективные материалы
2.2. Испытательно...
2.2.1. Оборудование ...
Список товаров и технологий двойного назначения...
Раздел 4. Товары и технологии...
Категория 2. Перспективные материалы
2.2. Испытат...
2.2.2. Оборуд...

but I want:
Список товаров и технологий..
Раздел 4. Товары и технологии..
Категория 2. Персп..
2.2. Ис..
2.2.1. Об..
2.2.2. Обор..
This rule should be applied on any level

Comment: I have demonstrated above in my question what output I need to get when choosing multiple positions that have common categories on some levels.

Comment: thank you, your solution will be enough for my needs, you saved me much time, because it's first time I work with xslt, and only second week I am looking into it. Now I am starting realize it has much more possibilities than I thought first=)

Comment: I am confused now with match patterns I need to set for templates in your proposed solution to make it work with WordML xslt template. In fact I have a little bit different xml structure, it looks like `<Goods><id = "1"><list><part><pos/></part></list><list><part><pos/></part></list></Goods><Goods><id= "2"><list><part><pos/></part></list></Goods>` And all the templates have match patterns like, for example for <pos>: "/ns1:Work/ns1:Goods/ns1:list/ns1:part/ns1:pos". If I add a template with match pattern like "*" word document gives me an error when I try to generate it with xslt transformation

Comment: @AnnaGulich at this point I suggest you ask a separate Stack Overflow question (linked back to this one) and include the actual XML you require as output (the markup as a code block, not an ASCII-art representation of how it renders in word).

Comment: [Here it is](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19378689/messing-xsl-match-patterns-forming-wordml-document)