# Messing XSL match patterns forming WordML document

Tags: xml, xslt, wordml

I have an xml structure. In xslt template for each position () in each list() I need to find position which attribute @out = 1, then I need to create a tree structure of categories it belongs to using positon's @pid attribute.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <Work>
    <Goods>
        <id="2196">
            <list  num="1050" id = "2531" description="Список оборудования и материалов двойного назначения и соответствующих технологий, применяемых в ядерных целях">
              <part  num="1">
                <pos  isKey="0" id="2532" pid="2531" description="Раздел 1. Промышленное оборудование" />
                <pos  num="1.2." isKey="0" id="2554" pid="2532" description="Испытательное и производственное оборудование" />
                <pos  num="1.2.6." isKey="0" id="2591" pid="2554" description="Системы для вибрационных испытаний, оборудование и компоненты, такие, как:" />
                <pos  num="1.2.6.1." isKey="1" id="2592" pid="2591" description="Электродинамические системы для вибрационных испытаний" />
                <pos  num="1.2.6.4." isKey="1" id="2595" pid="2591" description="Конструкции для крепления испытуемой детали и электронные блоки" />
              </part>
            </list>
            <list  num="1090" id = "3029" description="Список оборудования, материалов и технологий, которые могут быть использованы при создании ракетного оружия">
              <part  num="2">
                <pos  isKey="0" id="3033" pid="3029" description="КАТЕГОРИЯ II" />
                <pos  isKey="0" id="3040" pid="3033" description="Раздел 9. Измерительное, навигационное и пеленгаторное оборудование и системы" />
                <pos  isKey="0" id="3041" pid="3033" description="Раздел 10. Системы управления полетом" />
                <pos  isKey="0" id="3043" pid="3033" description="Раздел 12. Оборудование для обеспечения пуска" />
                <pos  isKey="0" id="3046" pid="3033" description="Раздел 15. Испытательные системы и оборудование" />
                <pos  num="9.2." isKey="0" id="3333" pid="3040" description="Испытательное и производственное оборудование" />
                <pos  num="9.2.1." isKey="0" id="3334" pid="3333" description="Производственное, испытательное.." />
                <pos  num="9.2.1.2" isKey="0" id="3339" pid="3334" description="Испытательное оборудование для инерциальной аппаратуры:" />
                <pos  num="9.2.1.2.3." isKey="1" id="3342" pid="3339" description="Испытательный стенд стабилизирующего элемента ИИБ;" />
                <pos  num="9.2.1.2.5." isKey="1" id="3344" pid="3339" description="Установка для проверки и настройки гироскопа;" />
                <pos  num="9.2.1.2.9." isKey="1" id="3348" pid="3339" description="Центрифуга для проверки подшипников (опор) гироскопа;" />
                <pos  num="9.2.1.2.10." isKey="1" out="1" id="3349" pid="3339" description="Установка для осевой регулировки акселерометра;" />
                <pos  num="9.2.1.2.11." isKey="1" id="3350" pid="3339" description="Установка для проверки акселерометра" />
                <pos  num="9.2.2." isKey="0" id="3351" pid="3333" description="Испытательное, калибровочное и регулировочное оборудование:" />
                <pos  num="9.2.2.3." isKey="1" id="3354" pid="3351" description="Динамические моделирующие стенды/столы вращения)" />
                <pos  num="9.2.2.4." isKey="1" id="3355" pid="3351" description="Поворотные столы" />
                <pos  num="9.2.2.5." isKey="1" id="3356" pid="3351" description="Центрифуги, способные создавать ускорения более 100 g" />
                <pos  num="10.2." isKey="0" id="3373" pid="3041" description="Испытательное и производственное оборудование" />
                <pos  num="10.2.1." out = "1" isKey="1" id="3374" pid="3373" description="Испытательное, калибровочное и регулировочное оборудование" />
                <pos  num="12.1." isKey="0" id="3399" pid="3043" description="Оборудование, сборочные единицы и комплектующие" />
                <pos  num="12.1.1." isKey="1" id="3400" pid="3399" description="Устройства и приборы, разработанные или модифицированные для обслуживания, проверки" />
            </part>
            </list>
            <list  num="1030" id="6648" description="Список товаров и технологий двойного назначения, которые могут быть использованы при создании вооружений и военной техники">
              <part  num="4">
                <pos  isKey="0" id="6679" pid="6648" description="Раздел 4. Товары и технологии, вывоз которых с территории РФ" />
                <pos  isKey="0" id="6681" pid="6679" description="Категория 2. Перспективные материалы" />
                <pos  num="2.2." isKey="0" id="11599" pid="6681" description="Испытательное, контрольное и производственное оборудование" />
                <pos  num="2.2.1." out = "1" isKey="1" id="11600" pid="11599" description="Оборудование для тепловых испытаний образцов материалов с углерод-углеродным покрытием" />
    <pos  num="2.2.2." out = "1" isKey="1" id="11600" pid="11599" description="Оборудование для тепловых испытаний образцов материалов с углерод-углеродным покрытием" />
        </Goods>
        <Goods>
        <id="2111">
        </Goods>
         <Goods>
        <id="2112">
        </Goods>
    </Work>
```

For example if I want 4 positions with nums "9.2.1.2.10", "10.2.1","2.2.1","2.2.2" to be detailed for good with id=2196, I need some output like that:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Список оборудования, материалов и технологий, которые могут быть использованы |
| при создании ракетного оружия                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| КАТЕГОРИЯ II                                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Раздел 9. Измерительное, навигационное и пеленгаторное оборудование и системы |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 9.2.       | Испытательное и производственное оборудование                    |
| 9.2.1.     | Производственное, испытательное..                                |
| 9.2.1.2.   | Испытательное оборудование для инерциальной аппаратуры           |
| 9.2.1.2.10.| Установка для осевой регулировки акселерометра                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Раздел 10. Системы управления полетом                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 10.2.      | Испытательное и производственное оборудование                    |
| 10.2.1     | Испытательное, калибровочное и регулировочное оборудование       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Список товаров и технологий двойного назначения, которые могут быть           |
|использованы при создании вооружений и военной техники                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Раздел 4. Товары и технологии, вывоз которых с территории РФ                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Категория 2. Перспективные материалы                                          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 2.2.       | Испытательное, контрольное и производственное оборудование       |
| 2.2.1.     | Оборудование для тепловых испытаний образцов материалов...       |
| 2.2.2.     | Оборудование для тепловых испытаний образцов материалов...       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The following code for templates using for forming Word Document gives an error when trying to open a document:

```
  <xsl:template match="ns1:*"  mode="table1">
      <w:p wsp:rsidR="00785C21" wsp:rsidRPr="00A33D80" wsp:rsidRDefault="00785C21" wsp:rsidP="007E1332">
        <w:pPr>

        </w:pPr>
        <w:r>
          <w:rPr>
            <w:lang w:val="EN-US" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>
            <xsl:text>Table output</xsl:text>
          </w:t>
        </w:r>

      </w:p>
    <xsl:variable name="shouldOutput">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="shouldOutput" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($shouldOutput)">
      <w:tbl>
        <w:tblPr>
          <w:tblW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
          <w:tblLook w:val="04A0" />
        </w:tblPr>
        <w:tblGrid>
          <w:gridCol w:w="222" />
          <w:gridCol w:w="222" />
        </w:tblGrid>

        <w:p wsp:rsidR="00785C21" wsp:rsidRPr="00A33D80" wsp:rsidRDefault="00785C21" wsp:rsidP="007E1332">
          <w:pPr>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r>
            <w:rPr>
              <w:lang w:val="EN-US" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>
              <xsl:text>Table output should output</xsl:text>
            </w:t>
          </w:r>

        </w:p>

        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
      </w:tbl>
      <!--</table>-->
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template> <!--Matching analysis table-->


  <xsl:template match="ns1:*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="row" />
    <xsl:for-each select="key('elementsByPid', @id)">
      <xsl:variable name="shouldOutput">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="shouldOutput" />
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:if test="string-length($shouldOutput)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." />
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template><!-- the main recursive logic - first produce output for this row, then
       process any of the children (in the id->pid chain) that need to be
       output -->

  <xsl:template match="ns1:*" mode="row">
    <w:tr wsp:rsidR="007E1332" wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540" wsp:rsidTr="005C4540">
    <w:tc>

      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto" />
        <w:hmerge w:val="restart"/>
      </w:tcPr>

      <w:p wsp:rsidR="007E1332" wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540" wsp:rsidRDefault="007E1332" wsp:rsidP="005C4540">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:spacing w:before="20" w:after="20" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>

        <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540">
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:h-ansi="Calibri" w:cs="Calibri" />
            <wx:font wx:val="Calibri" />
            <w:b w:val="off" />
            <w:color w:val="auto" />
            <w:lang w:val="EN-US" />
          </w:rPr>
          <w:t>
            <xsl:value-of select="@description" />
          </w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>


    <w:tc>

      <w:tcPr>
        <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
        <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto" />
        <w:hmerge w:val ="continue"/>
      </w:tcPr>

      <w:p wsp:rsidR="007E1332" wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540" wsp:rsidRDefault="007E1332" wsp:rsidP="005C4540">
        <w:pPr>
          <w:spacing w:before="20" w:after="20" />
          <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" />
          </w:rPr>
        </w:pPr>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>

    </w:tr>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="ns1:pos[@num]" mode="row">
    <w:tr wsp:rsidR="007E1332" wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540" wsp:rsidTr="005C4540">

      <w:tc>

        <w:tcPr>
          <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
          <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto" />
        </w:tcPr>

        <w:p wsp:rsidR="007E1332" wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540" wsp:rsidRDefault="007E1332" wsp:rsidP="005C4540">
          <w:pPr>
            <w:spacing w:before="20" w:after="20" />
            <w:rPr>
              <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" />
            </w:rPr>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540">
            <w:rPr>
              <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:h-ansi="Calibri" w:cs="Calibri" />
              <wx:font wx:val="Calibri" />
              <w:b w:val="off" />
              <w:color w:val="auto" />
              <w:lang w:val="EN-US" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>
              <xsl:value-of select="@num" />
            </w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>

      </w:tc>


      <w:tc>

        <w:tcPr>
          <w:tcW w:w="0" w:type="auto" />
          <w:shd w:val="clear" w:color="auto" w:fill="auto" />
        </w:tcPr>

        <w:p wsp:rsidR="007E1332" wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540" wsp:rsidRDefault="007E1332" wsp:rsidP="005C4540">
          <w:pPr>
            <w:spacing w:before="20" w:after="20" />
            <w:rPr>
              <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial" />
            </w:rPr>
          </w:pPr>
          <w:r wsp:rsidRPr="005C4540">
            <w:rPr>
              <w:rFonts w:ascii="Calibri" w:h-ansi="Calibri" w:cs="Calibri" />
              <wx:font wx:val="Calibri" />
              <w:b w:val="off" />
              <w:color w:val="auto" />
              <w:lang w:val="EN-US" />
            </w:rPr>
            <w:t>
              <xsl:value-of select="@description" />
            </w:t>
          </w:r>
        </w:p>
      </w:tc>

    </w:tr>

  </xsl:template> <!-- special case for pos elements with a @num - produce two columns -->



  <xsl:template match="ns1:*[@out='1']" mode="shouldOutput">1</xsl:template>
  <!-- check whether this node should be output by checking whether it, or any
       of its descendants in the id->pid tree, has @out=1.  The template will
       return an empty RTF for nodes that should not be output, and an RTF
       containing a text node with one or more "1" characters for nodes that
       should.  -->

  <xsl:template match="ns1:*" mode="shouldOutput">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elementsByPid', @id)" mode="shouldOutput"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

At the top of the xsl stylesheet I have a key declaration:

```
  <!-- key to look up any element with an id attribute based on the value of
       that id -->
  <xsl:key name="elementsByPid" match="ns1:*[@pid]" use="@pid" />
```

In main template for Goods:

```
<xsl:template match="/ns1:Work/ns1:Goods">
    <ns1:Goods>
      <xsl:for-each select="@ns1:*|@*[namespace-uri()='']">
        <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
          <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:for-each>

<!--Here is some WordML code-->

<!--Here I call to one of the above templates to form lists for the current good-->
<xsl:apply-templates select="ns1:list" mode="table" />

    </ns1:Goods>
  </xsl:template><!--/Goods товары в блоке описания-->
```

I can't find where is the mistake, but I think I've messed something with match patterns, because for simple html file everything worked fine

Comment: The input XML you've given is not well formed (e.g. `<id="2196">`), and not consistent with the XSLT (you're using a namespace prefix in your match expressions but there are no namespaces in the input).  Can you fix this so the question makes sense, and also give an example of the output XML (the XML tags, not a visual rendering of how they are interpreted by word) that you want the stylesheet to produce?

Comment: Is it for Ministry of War? :D

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk For goods export control =)

Comment: @AnnaGulich, kinda questionably... :)

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk, haha, we work under cover =)

Comment: @IanRoberts I have simplified my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382073/xsl-structure-for-category-tree-for-multiple-goods) . I think if I get the answer to it I should manage to understand how to solve the question I've described here.